# получение доступа к БД SQLite из ContentProvider

Tags: android, sqlite, contentprovider

У меня есть База данных приложения в SQLite.
Создание базы данных происходит в MyApplication:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    sInstance = this;
    initDBHelper();
    initaliseDataBase();
}

private void initDBHelper(){
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
}
```

В самом `DBHelper`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    NoteTable.createTable(db);
}
```

И наконец в NoteTable:

```
    public static void createTable(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase){
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
            + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement,"
            + COLUMN_DATE_CREATE + " text,"
            + COLUMN_DATE_EDIT + " text,"
            + COLUMN_AUTHOR + " text,"
            + COLUMN_TITLE + " text,"
            + COLUMN_BODY_NOTE + " text);");
}
```

В настоящий момент пишу `ContentProvider`, в котором получаю доступ к созданной БД таким образом:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreate");
    dbHelper = MyApplication.getInstance().getDbHelper();
    return true;
}
```

В итоге приложение падает с ошибкой NullPointerException в этой сроке - `dbHelper = MyApplication.getInstance().getDbHelper();`
Получается, что БД не успевает создаться?
Не обязательно же писать именно в `ContentProvider` код для создания БД?

Comment: вы должны получить объект самой базы методом `getWritableDatabase()`/`getReadableDatabase()`. Где вы это сделаете  - не важно, но работать с БД вы можете только через объект, который вернет один из этих методов.

Comment: @pavlofff Подскажите пожалуйста, я правильно понимаю, что я сначала должен создать объект dbHelper. А потом уже через этот объект подключится к базе данных через указанные Вами методы getWritableDatabase()/getReadableDatabase().

Comment: да, так и есть      .

Comment: Но смотрите, я пытаюсь получить доступ к уже созданному объекту в MyApplication - dbHelper = MyApplication.getInstance().getDbHelper(). И уже на этом этапе приложение падает с ошибкой NullPointerException. Получается, что ContentProvider создаётся раньше MyApplication?